# Reducing the default spacing between html tr tags

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I reduce the spacing between `<tr>` table tags?  I want to go below a cellspacing of 0.  In other words, I want the rows to almost touch each other.

I have:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr class="row"><td>One</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Two</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have tried a CSS similar to the following:

```
.table{ font-size: 12px; padding: 0;  margin:0;    }
.row{    height: 30px    }  / *tried playing with this to no avail */
```

with no success--the table rows do not get any closer than the default.

Answer (score 0):

```
.table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
} 

.table tr td{
     height: 30px;
     padding: 0;
}
```

Not sure about standarts, but I noticed that only rules which I use for TD works, not for TR!